# Java JTable combobox validation

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, jcombobox

There are 3 things i am trying to do here:

1. First i am trying to make the combo box to show "not feed" when u lanuch the program, at the moment when it launches it just shows nothing, only when i click on the combo box it shows the option "feed" and "not feed".
2. Secondly i am trying to do a validation for the combobox, where when i click the `JButton` next, it will validate if the combobox are all "feed" if so you go next, else it will have a pop up saying "check again"
3. Lastly, i would like to make the cells on the first 4 col uneditable and the last column editable.

   ```
   public class DosageTableHelper  {
   private static JTable toDoTable;
   private static JScrollPane jpane;
   private static int counter=1;
   public static DefaultTableModel getElderlyFromQueryDos(String timing,String position) throws SQLException {
       SQLObject so = new SQLObject();
       ResultSet rs = null;

       if(timing.equalsIgnoreCase("Morning")){
           PreparedStatement stmt  = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT morningdosage FROM et_elderly WHERE name = ?");
           stmt.setString(1,position);
           stmt.executeQuery();
           System.out.println(stmt);
           rs = stmt.getResultSet();
       }
       else if(timing.equalsIgnoreCase("Afternoon")){
           PreparedStatement stmt  = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT afternoondosage FROM et_elderly WHERE name = ?");
           stmt.setString(1,position);
           stmt.executeQuery();
           System.out.println(stmt);
           rs = stmt.getResultSet();
       }
       else if(timing.equalsIgnoreCase("Noon")){
           PreparedStatement stmt  = so.getPreparedStatementWithKey("SELECT noondosage FROM et_elderly WHERE name = ?");
           stmt.setString(1,position);
           stmt.executeQuery();
           System.out.println(stmt);
           rs = stmt.getResultSet();
       }
       return (DefaultTableModel) buildTableModel(rs);
   }



   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
       ArrayList<DosageObject> DosageList=null;


       System.out.println(rs);
       try {
           while(rs.next()){
               ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes(1));
               ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
               Object retrieveDosBlob =(Object) is.readObject();
               if(retrieveDosBlob instanceof  ArrayList<?>){
                   DosageList=((ArrayList<DosageObject>) retrieveDosBlob);
               }
           }
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       // storing array list in an array list for future uses

       Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

       columnNames.add("Description");
       columnNames.add("Prescription");
       columnNames.add("Medication Type");
       columnNames.add("Dosage");
       columnNames.add("Checked");

       Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();





       for(int k=0;k<DosageList.size();k++){
           Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
           vector.add(DosageList.get(k).getMedDescrip());
           vector.add(DosageList.get(k).getMedPrescrip());
           vector.add(DosageList.get(k).getMedType());
           vector.add(DosageList.get(k).getMedDosage());

           data.add(vector);
       }


       DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 4234183862785566645L;

           @Override
           public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
               return !( rowIndex == 1 && columnIndex == 1 );
           }


       };
       return dtm;
   }


   // Debug-able main method
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
       ArrayList<String> nameList= new ArrayList<String>();
       nameList.add("Lee Ching Chong");
       nameList.add("Lim Kuay Siak");
       nameList.add("Lee Ching Chong");

       toDoTable =new JTable(getElderlyFromQueryDos("morning",nameList.get(0)));


       String[] values = new String[] { "Not Feed", "Feed" };
       TableColumn col = toDoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
       col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(values));
       col.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(values));

       jpane = new JScrollPane(toDoTable);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 543);
       panel.add(jpane);
       frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel));

       JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
       panel.add(btnNext);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                   toDoTable.setModel(DosageTableHelper.getElderlyFromQueryDos("morning",nameList.get(counter)));
                   String[] values = new String[] { "Not Feed", "Feed" };
                   TableColumn col = toDoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
                   col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(values));
                   col.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(values));
               } catch (SQLException e1) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }



               counter++;

           }

       });

   }



   }
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1319299961084034009L;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
       super(items);
   }

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
           boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
       if (isSelected) {
           setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
           super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
       } else {
           setForeground(table.getForeground());
           setBackground(table.getBackground());
       }
       setSelectedItem(value);
       return this;
   }
   }
   class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1702063500403826596L;

   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
   public MyComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
       super(new JComboBox(items));
   }
   }
   ```

Sample Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. read Oracle tutorial - [How to use tables - part about to use JComboBox as TableCellEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox),

   - explanation `JTable` has two separate funcionalities `TableCellEditor` for editing the value stored in the `XxxTableModel` and `TableCellRenderer` for painting the value stored in `XxxTableModel`,
   - after editing you (event, notifiers implemented in APIs) just storing selected value from `TableCellEditor` (`JComboBox`) to the `XxxTableModel` by using `XxxTableModel.setValueAt`, to store `"feed"` or `"not feed"`, not `JComboBox` as `Object`, `TableCellRenderer` just painting from model to the view
   - by default everything works automatically by using `DefaultTableModel`, then there is required to override reduced numbers of methods (`getColumnClass`, `isCellEditeble`, in your case `setValueAt` probably too)
2. there are two ways (1st. required to override `XxxTableModel.setValueAt`)

   - `JButton` will be disabled (programatically) untill all value will be changed from blank to `"feed"` or `"not feed"`, required to loop inside the model, note after code line `super.setValueAt()` is executed, value from editor is stored to the model
   - action from `JButton` loops inside model (primitive, easiest, but themost efficient for validations, simple and direct code, without bugs inside `XxxTableModel.setValueAt`)
3. required to override `XxxTableModel.setValueAt` and to set, change `isCellEditable(row, column)` to correct value, it would be need to create separate array for `isCellEditable`, just for models events, don't to change this array from outside, just method  `XxxTableModel.setValueAt` can be notifier

---

- use `DefaultTableModel` if is possible (to avoids any missinterpretations in the code that required for override `AbstractTableModel`, methods, listeners and especially models notifiers - `fireXxxXxx`)
- code ordering inside model is important, firstly to to store value to the model, then to call any changes, validations, additional code, just code based on value stored in model
- I'm sure that every three points are here a few times, including working code examples in SSCCE / MCVE forms